# How to leave comma space off end of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to finish this program, and ran into an issue I can't quite figure out. I want to change the array of numbers into a string of their ordinal counter parts, which I have completed with this program, I would just like the last value to leave of the concatenated ', ' (comma space). I tried using an if statement but can't quite get it to work.

```
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
   v=n%100;
return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var n = "";
for ( var i = 0; i <= getGetOrdinal(4).length; i++ ) {
        if ( n < getGetOrdinal(n) ) {
            n += getGetOrdinal(nums[i]) + ', ';
                console.log(n);
    }  
} // ['1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th'] < ~ expected result
```

Comment: How about `Array#join` ?

Comment: I just *love* this elegant solution for generating the ordinal numbers. This was published earlier on [shopify](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/ordinal-number-in-javascript-1st-2nd-3rd-4th-29259).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options:

One way is to add check inside the `for` loop which will *prepend* a comma only if it is not the first iteration of the loop:

```
for (var i=0; i <= getGetOrdinal(4).length; i++) {
    if (n < getGetOrdinal(n)) {
        if (i > 0) {
            n += ', ';
        }
        n += getGetOrdinal(nums[i]);
    }  
}
console.log(n);
```

Another option would be to leave your code as is, but then substring off the trailing comma:

```
for (var i=0; i <= getGetOrdinal(4).length; i++) {
    if (n < getGetOrdinal(n)) {
        n += getGetOrdinal(nums[i]) + ', ';
    }
}

//n = n.substring(0, n.length - 2);
n = n.slice(0, -2);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: For the second option it is simpler to use `n = n.slice(0, -2)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> undefined
nums.map(getGetOrdinal).join(', ')
> "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may utilize `Array.prototype.join` to join an array with specified separator:

```js
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
  var s = ["th","st","nd","rd"],
      v = n % 100;
  return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var numsWithOrdinal = nums.map(getGetOrdinal);

var joined = numsWithOrdinal.join(', ');
console.log(joined);
```

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh, thanks :) Was thinking about an opposite operation. English is not my primary language.

Comment: I was just being pedantic. English is my *only* language, so I admire everybody who speaks more than one language.